# Error on rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have you an idea about this error message when i run the rake db:migrate
command under Aptana ?

rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `ord' for 0:Fixnum: SET
SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0

Thanks

Here My Config :
Windows XP PRO SP2
Wamp 2.0
Aptana 2.0.4
RubyGems 1.3.5
Ruby 1.8.6

Answer (score 0):

Check your log with [rake db:migrate --trace] to see where it's breaking. You probably tried to use an invalid type in your migrations file.

Comment: I looked at the log file, but I did not find anything; it indicates an error on all the functions execute,configure_connection, .. on mysql_adaptater.rb file (here the logfile:http://patxi.mayol.free.fr/public/logfile.html)